# JAVA 8u77 classLoader bug - looking for a workaround

Tags: java, jar, classpath, java-web-start

JAVA 8u77 was released last week (March 23, 2016)

Hi have posted a month ago a related question (regarding JAVA 8u74) – I am posting now as a new question since we have more accurate information and my question is slightly different.

With my web start application, if the client installed the update, he will get errors while running:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: 
       Could not verify signing in resource: https://www.example.com:443/app/myFile.jar
       at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.ensureAllJarEntriesSigned(Unknown Source)
       ….
```

Diving into the code I noticed the error is produced for the following line:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
classLoader.getResource("").getPath();
```

the second line returns NULL.

This code works with JAVA 8u73 and earlier.
Oracle confirmed it is a bug - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152827

Yet, I am not sure I can wait for a bug fix…
We are trying to find a workaround…

This is what I found -

The JAR files we are trying to access with classloader are not part of the classpath of the application.
They contain files which are not part of the JAVA code.

We noticed that if adding a class file to the JAR and then setting the JAR as part of the project and classpath, the error does not reproduce.

But our problem is we have a long a dynamic list of JAR files (we create new JARs on a regular basis).
Each time the application is loading (using JNLP file) – we dynamically add the necessary JARs to the JNLP file list.
It will be impossible for us to make a new deployment of the application for each new JAR we create. (as mentioned – these JARs have no JAVA code.)

Of-course all jars are signed with the same trusted certificate.
And – again – worked with no problem on 8u73.

Does anyone have an idea for a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: I would have thought the workaround is to use a version without this bug. I am guessing you can't control which version is used?

Comment: Yes - Currently I am asking customers not to install the update.

Comment: I assume Oracle have no idea how to workaround this as they understand the bug possibly better than anyone.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as 8u77. 8u73 seems to work just fine... Any updates allready?

Comment: Seems to be fixed in 8u91

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has information about this bug here, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151624, but the general public doesn't have read access to that url. (I don't either, but the bug you linked is marked as a duplicate of the hidden bug.)

So there's nothing we can do, there's no communication about it from Oracle, and the workaround is to use 8u73.

You'll have to uninstall your previous JRE manually ( http://java.com/newerversionexists will redirect you to instructions based on your browser's OS), then download 8u73 here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jre-8u73-oth-JPR

But: you will have to register for an Oracle account and give them your email address, phone number, etc in order for the download link to work.

Great work, Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 8u73 works indeed. Hopefully this gets fixed soon by Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this problem when calling ClassLoader.getResource / getResourceAsStream, but not when calling getResources. So a possible workaround might be to use:

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("some/path").

The path should be absolute but not start with a '/'.
The return type is an Enumeration of URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I have an application with exactly the same problem (stacktrace as in the question). Everything is working with `8u73`.

With `8u74` the error is reproducible every time with `Java Control Panel` - Temporary Files Settings - "Keep Temporary Files On My Computer" checked. If unchecked the error does not reproduce.

The same behavior applies to `8u77`. Only difference I found so far: If "Keep Temporary Files On My Computer" is first unchecked and then checked again, the error is not reproducible every time. Reason for this is unknown.

Please be aware that unchecking this option in `Java Control Panel` may decrease performance of your application. Nevertheless depending on your clients and application this may be a better workaround than just asking not to update.

Answer (score 0):

We found that this exception in JRE 8u74-77 is caused by loading resources from another JAR. So `this.getClass()` is not good enough. Another example, the call to `ResourceBundle.getBundle()` should have third parameter - loader for the class from the JAR where resources are located. There is also an option to shuffle resource files between JARs. There is even more trouble with 3-rd party libraries, like SwingX.

Its weird that the thrown exception is `CertificateException` when more appropriate would be "Resource not found".

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for me have been declaring the dependencies in the jnlp archive **without** using the "version" tag.

So, for example, this way works fine:

```
<jar href="spring-aop-u15-2.5.5.jar"/>
```

This solution has the followin lateral effect:

- The version-download protocol does not take effect, so every time the user executes the application, jws will ask the server for the each jar contained in the application. The jar will not be updated but because probably the server will response with an 304 indicating that it is already updated, but if your application contains a lot of libraries you will have some latency starting the application beacause will be one http request for each library.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested 1.8u91 and the issue has not been fixed as was indicated in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

Dark move it seems. Apparently customers on Java SE Advanced could take advantage of the bug fix straight away but the non paying customers are still waiting for the first GA release containing the bug fix. Plus the whole thing of the public JBS issues marked as duplicates of private issues whose status can not be seen.